# Summaring reports using itertools.groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone help me do group by function first column, second column and sum third column.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

things = [('2009-09-02','j', 12),
          ('2009-09-02','j', 3),
          ('2009-09-03','k',10),
          ('2009-09-03','k',4),
          ('2009-09-03','u', 22),
          ('2009-09-06','m',33)]

for k, items in groupby(things, itemgetter(1)):    
    for subitem in items:
        print(subitem)
```

got this result:

```
('2009-09-02', 'j', 12) ('2009-09-02', 'j', 3) ('2009-09-03', 'k', 10) ('2009-09-03', 'k', 4) ('2009-09-03', 'u', 22) ('2009-09-06', 'm', 33)
```

expecting this result:

```
 ('2009-09-02', 'j', 15) ('2009-09-03', 'k', 14) ('2009-09-03', 'u', 22) ('2009-09-06', 'm', 33)
```

========================================================================

```
   sales = [('Scotland', 'Edinburgh', 20000),
         ('Scotland', 'Glasgow', 12500),
         ('Wales', 'Cardiff', 29700),
         ('Wales', 'Bangor', 12800),
         ('England', 'London', 90000),
         ('England', 'Manchester', 45600),
         ('England', 'London', 29700)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> for a, b in groupby(things, itemgetter(0, 1)):
...     print(a, sum(lst[2] for lst in b))

('2009-09-02', 'j') 15
('2009-09-03', 'k') 14
('2009-09-03', 'u') 22
('2009-09-06', 'm') 33
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `groupby` as a more efficient way you can use dictionary with `dict.setdefault` method :

```
>>> d={}
>>> 
>>> for date,char,val, in things:
...       d.setdefault((date,char),[]).append(val)
... 
>>> [(i,j,sum(k)) for (i,j),k in d.items()]
[('2009-09-02', 'j', 15), ('2009-09-03', 'u', 22), ('2009-09-06', 'm', 33), ('2009-09-03', 'k', 14)]
>>>
```

And if you want to use `groupby` as a hint you might note that you need to  pass the indices to `itemgetter` function :

```
itemgetter(0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `sum` , you have to sum , simply printing it wouldn't magically sum the values for you.

Also, according to your example, seems like you should groupby based on first and second column. Example -

```
for k,items in groupby(things, itemgetter(0, 1)):    
    print(k + (sum(x[2] for x in items),)
```

Comment: thanks Sharon. I have include one more a sale example above. however it won't summarise England & London for some reason ?